# C For only print last index input

Tags: c

im trying to do a programa  in C. Capture name, age, album number, names and songs withing each album. Im ok but it only prints the last albums name. Lets say i input 3 albums, "a", "b" and "c". It would only print c 3 times. And it should be a,b and c. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

//variables
int edadCantante;
int x,numeroCanciones[x];
char nombreCantante;
char nombreDiscos[30][x];

printf("Introduzca el nombre del artista: ");
scanf(" %[^\n]",nombreCantante);
printf("Introduzca edad del artista: ");
scanf("%d", &edadCantante);

printf("Introduzca número de discos: ");
scanf("%d\n",&x );
// taking input and storing it in an array
for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
  scanf("%[^\n]%*c", nombreDiscos[i]);

}

printf("Desplegando albumes:\n ");

// printing elements of an array
 for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
  printf("%s\n", nombreDiscos[i]);
}

printf("Número de canciones por album respectivamente:\n ");
for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
      scanf("%d", &numeroCanciones[i]);

}

printf("Desplegando número de canciones:\n ");

// printing elements of an array
 for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
  printf("Número de canciones en album %d = %d\n",i+1,numeroCanciones[i]);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: `int x,numeroCanciones[x]; char nombreDiscos[30][x];` That's not correct and results in undefined behaviour because `x` is not set when the arrays are declared.

Comment: //variables
  int edadCantante;

  char nombreCantante[30];

    printf("Introduzca el nombre del artista: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]",nombreCantante);
    printf("Introduzca edad del artista: ");
    scanf("%d", &edadCantante);
    int x;
    printf("Introduzca número de discos: ");
    scanf("%d\n",&x );
    int numeroCanciones[x];
    char nombreDiscos[30][x];
I modified it like this and now it print something like: abc,bc,c. It prints the index in that order and not a,b,c.

Comment: @Tejon please [edit] the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the declaration of `numeroCanciones` and `nombreDiscos`. Like this:

```
int x;
scanf("%d\n",&x );
int numeroCanciones[x];
```

But don't forget to check the return value of `scanf` in case a reading failed.